# paper-drawer-panel drawer requires a double tap on paper-item

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

For some reason, the `drawer` portion in `paper-drawer-panel` requires a double tap **when** selecting paper-items, instead of a single tap like the rest of the app. Any ideas on how to make it a single tap?

**UPDATE**: To express the issue more clearly, the `drawer` has a feature where the first tap highlights  the selection with a grey bar and the second tap actually clicks/tap the item. This behavior is only on a touch screen, on a desktop one click with the mouse does both.

```
<paper-drawer-panel force-narrow id="the-drawer">
 <paper-header-panel drawer>      
  <template>
    <paper-menu attr-for-selected="name" selected="{{setSelected}}">
      <paper-item name="home" on-tap="jumpToPage">
        <paper-ripple></paper-ripple>
        HOME
      </paper-item>
      <paper-item name="portfolio" on-tap="jumpToPage">
        <paper-ripple></paper-ripple>
        PORTFOLIO
      </paper-item>
      <paper-item name="resume" on-tap="jumpToPage">
        <paper-ripple></paper-ripple>
        RESUME
      </paper-item>
      <paper-item name="contact" on-tap="jumpToPage">
        <paper-ripple></paper-ripple>
        CONTACT
      </paper-item>
    </paper-menu>
  </template>
```

---

```
Polymer({
    is: "paper-menu-custom",
    jumpToPage: function(e, detail) {
      pageJump = "/" + e.target.attributes.name.textContent;
      page(pageJump);
      drawer.closeDrawer();
    }
});
```

Comment: Would be useful if you could show us what jumpToPage was doing. I have on-tap in a similar but different circumstance and a single click with a mouse certainly works.  Haven't tried mine on an actual tablet through.

Comment: I updated the post with more detail information of the issue.

Comment: don't understand, what is this element paper-menu-custom, its not used in the piece above.  How is "setSelected" set?  Your description of the symptoms would make me look at whether the first tap was actually being prevented to bubbling somewhere.

Comment: It's a custom template, but I just pasted it as a non custom template for easy reading. IIf the first  tap is being prevented to bubble, why would the second tap work?